# How to disable or remove this prompt when install our app "Do you want to install this application? It does not require any special access"?

Tags: android, device-admin

Whenever I install my android application I am facing this prompt before getting installed. Is there anyway to remove or disable this prompt in programmatically?

What I want to achieve is, I want to send application file(apk) from server to mobile device by using device administration. Once I sent the app file then it should be getting downloaded and installed without any user permission. Because I want to restrict this through server.

Please give me any idea about this.

Comment: Outside of perhaps device owner APIs, or on rooted devices, this should not be possible.

Comment: @Sridhar Venkat you can't install any application without user permission, its OS responsibility to restrict installation of application without user permission

Comment: If you are publishing that on Google Play, have fun getting it rejected, because you are not allowed to install apps without the user's permission, and you are not allowed to use another update mechanism than the Google Play's one.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you please elaborate "device owner APIs" ? If we have anyway to do that with "device owner APIs" then shall we apply the apk in google play store?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#Enterprise